# Get hex colors of discrete colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following colorbar :

```
from matplotlib import cm

cmap = matplotlib.cm.Blues
bounds = [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N , extend = 'max')
plt.colorbar(matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), orientation='vertical')
```

Is there a way to get the hex codes of the six colors generated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `norm` object has a property `boundaries` - normalise those to the original cmap range, then `cmap` can convert those to RGBA 4-tuples, and then you can call `matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex`. Putting it all into a list comprehension gets you:

```
[matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex(cmap(norm(c))) for c in norm.boundaries]
```

Result:

```
['#f7fbff', '#d0e1f2', '#94c4df', '#4a98c9', '#1764ab', '#08306b']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the file as a JPG or PNG using the `savefig()` function in matplotlib. To find the hex codes, you can input the PIL library. The function `PIL.ImageColor.getrgb()` could then be used. (Of course, you first would have to use `from PIL import ImageColor`).